# tkinter submit button handle function only once unless different input is given

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and this is a simple method but I don't know how to do it. I want to create a submit button where if the same user input is given and submitted again the button will disable but if new input is given it will carry out its function. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Without seeing your attempts, this is just "write code for me" type of question which is not what SO is for.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: you will have to create list with already submited data and compare with new input and disable submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand problem - you have to create list to remeber submitted data and check it with new input

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def submit():
    data = e.get()

    if data in already_submitted:
        print('Sorry already submitted:', data)
    else:    
        print('Submit:', data)
        already_submitted.append(data)

# --- main ---

# don't submit empty string        
already_submitted = ['']

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** you could also `bind()` function to `Entry` and check input after every `key` and disable/enable button.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def submit():
    data = e.get()

    if data in already_submitted:
        print('Sorry already submitted:', data)
    else:    
        print('Submit:', data)
        already_submitted.append(data)
        b['state'] = 'disable'

def check(event):
    #data = event.widget.get()
    data = e.get()

    if data in already_submitted:
        b['state'] = 'disable'
    else:
        b['state'] = 'normal'

# --- main ---

# don't submit empty string        
already_submitted = ['']

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease>', check)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit, state='disable')
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you your previous answer enough that I had to make a list of already submitted data. This is more than enough.